# How to read context parameters using php webhook in dialogflow

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

Need help with the following I writing a webhook in php, and need the ability to read the context parameters.

Can someone help me to understand how it can be done?

Here is my example JSON:

```
{
     "id": "6e774dc2-2323-42b3-bd3c-ab64930f8b92",
      "timestamp": "2017-12-22T21:12:19.094Z",
      "lang": "en",
      "result": {
        "source": "agent",
        "resolvedQuery": "Yes",
        "action": "Triage.Triage-yes",
        "actionIncomplete": false,
        "parameters": {},
        "contexts": [
          {
            "name": "triage-followup",
            "parameters": {
              "triagecriteria": [],
              "roomEntity.original": "",
              "roomname": "300",
              "roomnames.original": "living",
              "roomid": "200",
              "context": "",
              "roomnames": [
                "living"
              ],
              "counter": "400",
              "roomEntity": "100",
              "triagecriteria.original": ""
            },
            "lifespan": 3
          }
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "intentId": "ecd4a2e5-65a0-41b2-ac72-edcf4d2e73f2",
          "webhookUsed": "true",
          "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
          "webhookResponseTime": 203,
          "intentName": "Triage - yes"
        },
        "fulfillment": {
          "speech": "Yes",
          "source": "agent",
          "displayText": "No",
          "messages": [
            {
              "type": 0,
              "speech": "Yes"
            }
          ]
        },
        "score": 1
      },
      "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "errorType": "success",
        "webhookTimedOut": false
      },
      "sessionId": "db8c1a4e-fa0c-4257-a536-78b63879eef9"
    }
```

I want to be able to refer to [results][Contexts][Parameters]

I am using

```
$update_response = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$update = json_decode($update_response, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

and trying to access the value as $update["results"]["Contexts"]["Parameters"]["roomid"]

Comment: Have you tried JSON Decode?

Comment: Yes I am using JSON Decode to parse.

Comment: I am using $update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update_response, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);    and trying to access the value as $update["results"]["Contexts"]["Parameters"]["roomid"]

Answer (score 0):

The names are case sensitive, and you need to be careful about trailing "s"es. Since some of the items are numerically indexed arrays, you'll need to include that as part of the index.  Try

```
$update["result"]["contexts"][0]["parameters"]["roomid"]
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Accepting and/or upvoting good answers are always appreciated.